# how to run only specified junit groups of tests in maven?

Tags: maven, testing, junit, categories

I run groups of junit tests using maven, two groups: junit unit tests not requiring any container, integration junit tests not requiring container but instead of running only this tests maven runs both them and all other tests in the directory:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <!-- <skipTests>false</skipTests> -->
        <parallel>both</parallel>
        <threadCount>10</threadCount>                            
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        <configuration>
            <groups>ru.package.IntegrationTestsNotRequiringContainerCategory</groups>
            <groups>ru.package.UnitTestsCategory</groups>
        </configuration>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

but this config runs all detected tests:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running javalangtests.AnnotationTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec
Running ru.project.envers.ModelInformationServiceTest
Tests run: 21, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.773 sec
Running ru.project.reflection.FieldServiceTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running ru.project.reflection.HibernateServiceTest
Tests run: 13, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.127 sec
```

Other tests fail without container but they must not be run at all:

```
Running ru.project.utils.ListUtilsTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
Running ru.project.jreports.JReportControllerTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.961 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running ru.project.map.MapTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.656 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running ru.project.TestCase
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

Comment: Which version of junit are you using? The groups stuff only works with the later versions (4.8+ I think)